# Does Pandas compare indexes when adding a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I add a column using apply on other columns, does panda store the result of this new column in the same row as the one used for the computation. If not how can I make it do it.

The reason why I'am not completely confident is following example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4], 'value':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,2,1,3,5], 'value':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df['second_value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
df['third_value'] = df2['value'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
df
```

The results this yields is

```
index value  second_value  third_value
0     1      1             1    
1     2      4             4    
2     3      9             9    
3     4      16            16
4     5      25            25
```

So what I see here is that pandas only checks for the order. So can it happen that a DataFrame is sorted at a random moment which could mess up or can I assume that the order is always preserved when I perform

```
df['new_value'] = df['old_value'].apply(...)
```

?

EDIT: In my original code snippet I forgot to set the index and that is actually where I was doing wrong. So I had `df.set_index('index')` and `df2.set_index('index')` before using apply. the problem is that this method creates a copy with the said index. So either you asign these to the original dataframes `df` and `df2` or even better you add `inline=True` in the method call in order to not create a copy and set the index in the given dataframe.

Comment: As long as the index is right , pandas will assign it base on match index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you define an index. You need to pass a list/iterable to the `index` keyword argument when calling the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=[0, 2, 1, 3, 4])

df['second'] = df['value'] ** 2
df['third'] = df2['value'] ** 2

df
   value  second  third
0      1       1      1
1      2       4      9    # note these 
2      3       9      4    # two rows
3      4      16     16
4      5      25     25
```

The assignment operations are always index aligned.

Comment: Yeah actually that was an error in my code snippet but I still figured it out. My problem was that I didn't assign set_index to the set again I was just calling the method which doesn't do a thing.

Comment: or even better I add the flag `inplace=True` so that I don't create a new dataframe